# Creating dialog in java/android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an error dialog that says "Wrong input : input".
My problem - "Wroing input" is pre-defined in the string file and thus have R.string.error int
number. The "input" is dynamic and I can only obtain it in runtime. 
the setMessage() method can work with either a char sequence or an int (for id),
so how can I concat it?
Hope I was clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can call [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) to obtain the string from the xml:

```
String msg = getString(R.string.error) + myDynamicStringMessage;
```

Note that getString is a context method, so make sure to call it from one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to create a String variable in which "wrong input" and "input" have been concatenated, then simply pass that String to the setMessage() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use getString() to obtain string from xml

you can use `setMessage(getString(R.string.error)+" My Dynamic Message")`

### Example

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(getString(R.string.error)+" My Dynamic Message")
        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", null).show();
```

Thanks
Deepak